# EditText not displaying entered text while setting ImageView as background of EditView and also while placing EditView over ImageView?

Tags: android

while i am placing `EditText` over an `ImageView` by using `android:layout_alignTop` property of `EditText` as below:-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/first_meddle_baar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_view"
        android:src="@drawable/top_meddle_baar" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/search_baar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_view"
        android:src="@drawable/search_baar" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/search_baar"    // #1
        android:layout_margin="3dip"
        android:hint="@string/search"
        android:paddingLeft="30dip" />
```

or if  i am placing an `EditText` over a `TextView` whose background i had set as an image as in the code below:-

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first_enter_code"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/first_center_back"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/enter_code_new"
        android:text="@string/enter_client_code"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/first_enter_code"    //#2
        android:layout_marginLeft="210dip"
        android:padding="15dp" />
```

In both the cases the text that is entered into `EditText` is not getting displayed ? why?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you and give background image to any text box you need not to take this separately in image view. This will resolve your problem of showing edittext.

Just like:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/search_baar"    
    android:layout_margin="3dip"
    android:background="@drawable/txt_view_bg"
    android:paddingLeft="30dip" />
```